# Show the first previous collapsible div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best (generic) way to do the following using jQuery. When clicking the anchor within `.story-collapse` I want to toggle the div `.collapse` in the `article` it resides in. This `article` is repeated several times on the page and of course only the current one should toggle.

```
<article>
    <div class="story-body clearfix">
        <div class="story-paragraph">
            <p>This is shown</p>
            <div class="collapse">
                <p>This is hidden</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="story-collapse"><a class="icon icon-icon-arrow-up" href="#"></a></div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest):

```
$('.story-collapse').on('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('article').find('.collapse').toggle();
});
```

Or, you can use [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev) and then [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the correct element:

```
$(this).prev().find('.collapse').toggle();
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the `.prev().find()` is the most elegant one.

Comment: you may use whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('.story-collapse').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('article').find('.collapse').toggle();
        // or
  $(this).parent().prev().find('.collapse').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to navigate up to `article` and [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get `.collapse`

```
$(this).closest('article').find('.collapse').toggle();
```

```js
$('.story-collapse a').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('article').find('.collapse').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <div class="story-body clearfix">
    <div class="story-paragraph">
      <p>This is shown</p>
      <div class="collapse">
        <p>This is hidden</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="story-collapse">
    <a class="icon icon-icon-arrow-up" href="#">toggle</a>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="story-body clearfix">
    <div class="story-paragraph">
      <p>This is shown</p>
      <div class="collapse">
        <p>This is hidden</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="story-collapse">
    <a class="icon icon-icon-arrow-up" href="#">toggle</a>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="story-body clearfix">
    <div class="story-paragraph">
      <p>This is shown</p>
      <div class="collapse">
        <p>This is hidden</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="story-collapse">
    <a class="icon icon-icon-arrow-up" href="#">toggle</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

**Or** using [**has()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('article').has(this).find('.collapse').toggle();
```

```js
$('.story-collapse a').click(function() {
  $('article').has(this).find('.collapse').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <div class="story-body clearfix">
    <div class="story-paragraph">
      <p>This is shown</p>
      <div class="collapse">
        <p>This is hidden</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="story-collapse">
    <a class="icon icon-icon-arrow-up" href="#">toggle</a>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="story-body clearfix">
    <div class="story-paragraph">
      <p>This is shown</p>
      <div class="collapse">
        <p>This is hidden</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="story-collapse">
    <a class="icon icon-icon-arrow-up" href="#">toggle</a>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="story-body clearfix">
    <div class="story-paragraph">
      <p>This is shown</p>
      <div class="collapse">
        <p>This is hidden</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="story-collapse">
    <a class="icon icon-icon-arrow-up" href="#">toggle</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parents will select the entire previous DOM elements, after getting article element we can find the `.collapse` class element using `.find()` method

```
$(".story-collapse a").click(function(){
    $(this).parents("article").find(".collapse").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: parents will select the entire previous DOM Elements, after getting article element we can find the .collapse class element using find method